# Where do I ask this followup question? Web app or extension development

Tags: support

[Reviewing Firefox Extensions - When was it installed?](https://superuser.com/q/1512094/627894) has an answer that with a bit of manual processing answers my question. However I'm not satisified with this solution and want an easy to read sortable table or list of extension name, extension AMO  link and install date (in human readable format).

Where can I ask for this to be developed or coded? What sites? Can it be asked on the stackexchange network?

Comment: No, Stack Exchange doesn't provide a script writing service. Perhaps you could start the development yourself?

Comment: I am a power user but by no means a coder.

Comment: Best time to learn!

Comment: There are no Stack Exchange communities where asking for the community to write software to generate a list of Firefox extensions would be within scope

Answer (score 2):

There's no Stack Exchange site where asking others to develop a tool for you would be on topic.

However, if you start developing this and run into a specific problem, you could ask for help on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).